# preg replace with arabic

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, arabic

I want to add a text to mysql with arabic characters, but I always get weird signs when i use preg replace.

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9_-äÄüÜöÖ]/isU', '', $str);
```

Comment: Hi, is this a mysql or php problem? What do you mean by "weird"?

Comment: [Now you have two problems.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html)

Comment: its a php problem, when i deleted the preg_replace line it works. the signs look like this: �����

Comment: Apparently, unicode is problematice in preg with PHP.

Comment: did you save the php file in UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: This looks like a codepage problem...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the small letter '/u' after the regular expression, e.g.

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^أب]/u', '', $str);
```

Notice that, same problem will occur whenever you use capital '/U' after the regular expression.